# MQTT-MQ data path load testing

Tags: multithreading, performance, load-testing, mqtt

We are implementing a communication system where client (mobile device) sends messages thru MQTT-MQ to the backend systems. I would like to benchmark the load performance of the MQTT-MQ data path.

Could you please recommend if there is any opensource (or commercial) performance test tool which could load test the MQTT-MQ data path.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it provides the following test elements:

- [JMS Publisher](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher)
- [JMS Subscriber](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Subscriber)
- [JMS Point-to-Point](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point)

which should be quite enough to conduct your testing.

Just download appropriate MQ Java client libraries, drop them to JMeter's /lib folder, restart JMeter and you should be able to use the relevant classes to send messages to queues and read them.

See the following reference guides:

- [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html)
- [Building a JMS Point-to-Point Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-point-to-point-test-plan.html)
- [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

Both [mqtt-spy](http://kamilfb.github.io/mqtt-spy/) and mqtt-spy-daemon support concurrent messaging. You can define a [script](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt-spy/wiki/Scripting) that sends messages concurrently, or multiple scripts which is normally easier. To have multiple concurrent MQTT clients connected to the broker/server, you can run multiple mqtt-spy connections or multiple mqtt-spy-daemon instances, each having their own configuration and scripts.